# Within a given RSpec describe block, does the order of let, before and it statements matter?

Tags: rspec

If I have a `describe` statement in RSpec with a set of `let`, `before` and `it` statements, does the specific interleaving of those statements affect the behavior as long as the order *within* a given type of statement is maintained? For example, will:

```
describe "ordering test" do
  <it1>
  <it2>
  <before1>
  <let1>
  <let2>
  <before2>
end
```

always produce the same result as:

```
describe "ordering test" do
  <let1>
  <let2>
  <before1>
  <before2>
  <it1>
  <it2>
end
```

where `<xxx1>` and `<xxx2>` are instances of the corresponding `xxx` statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the ordering does not matter, modulo any dependencies of the non-Proc arguments on top-level statements in the `describe` block.

Basically, the `describe` collects the values of all the arguments passed into its `let`, `before` and `it` statements, then executes all the `let`s, followed by all the `before`s, followed by all the `it`s.

The exception noted in the first sentence would be a rare occurrence, given normal RSpec usage.

Comment: great explanation. Is there a way to ignore that order? That would be useful to see how `let` affects the db.thanks